# when will arc be supported on windows chrome browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I have tested succefully my android app in windows chrome browser thanks to ARC & ARC welder. What is preventing me from distributing the generated zip for chrome browser? I assume there are not technical constraints as I can locally install the application in the browser.

I would just like to now distribute it to chrome os or chrome browser on windows/linux through the chrome webstore but when I try to install it from the chrome webstore I'm told the application requires chrome os, which is puzzling since I can run it in chrome browser.

Is this an issue of packaging the app and the app runtime for chrome or security ?

Any information from google team on the roadmap for running android app in chrome browser would be most welcome. Otherwise I do not really see the point of porting apps for the sole population of chrome os users.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a question that cannot really be answered with absolute certainty, unless you have insider information. If you want my 2¢, I think this will be an option when it is out of beta. I **believe** that they are restricting distribution to chrome os so that they do not have to support all distribution platforms while in beta, and will probably open up to other operating systems soon.